# Unable to remove query string in .htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have read many posts and documentation, and still cannot make this work. Probably missing something trivial.

I want `www.domain.no/?id=val` to rewrite to `www.domain.no/index.php`

The code in `.htaccess` is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

# Test that pathname exists, and is NOT a directory.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Test that the pathname with a .php extension exists, and is a regular file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
# Test that a non-empty query string exists
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
# Re-write to file with .php extension, without query string
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php? [L]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It should be `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=val$`

Comment: My understanding is that "RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ." matches any query string, which is what I want. I don't want to limit the rewrite to any specific queries.

Comment: The problem with `www.domain.no/?id=val`: no file with a .php extension exists...

Comment: I have an index file www.domain.no/index.php. The idea is that www.domain.no by default goes to the index.php file, which is does. But the query string remains in the URL display in the net browser.

Comment: In your htaccess, you add the .php extension to the file. And that work only in this case. You need to add more examples of what you want to do or not. And you talk about redirection, but you use a rewrite without redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Start by trying that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [R=302,L]
```